# Can't display data with MongoDB, Mongoose, Node.js and Express in CoffeeScript

Tags: mongodb, node.js, coffeescript, express, mongoose

I've got a Node.js, Express setup with Mongo and Mongoose written in CoffeeScript.

I can save data into my collection with this code:

```
# new
app.get "/admin/new", (req, res) ->
  res.render "admin/new.jade", locals: c: new Content()

# create
app.post "/admin.:format?", (req, res) ->
    content = new Content(req.body["content"])
    content.save ->
        switch req.params.format
            when "json"
                res.send content.__doc
            else
                res.redirect "/"
```

But I can't display any data with this code. The web browser just says "Waiting for localhost..." and the console says nothing.

```
# index
app.get "/admin.:format?", (req, res) ->
    Content.find().all (contents) ->
        switch req.params.format
            when "json"
                res.send contents.map((c) ->
                    c.__doc
                )
            else
                res.render "admin/index.jade", locals: contents: contents
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am taking a look at Moongoose documentation.

The [querying documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html) says if you do not specify a callback, you can use the [Query object](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js) to further refine your search, and the query object does not seem to specify a "all" function. Is your code silently failing?

I believe what you are really looking for is:

```
Content.find({}).exec (err, contents) ->
```

Comment: Thanks, workes fine now! Found that .all in a tutorial, perhaps an old one.

Comment: Ran in to some more problems with update, I made another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760838/cannot-post-with-node-js-express-mongodb-mongoose-coffeescript