# Cannot POST with Node.js Express MongoDB Mongoose CoffeeScript

Tags: mongodb, node.js, coffeescript, express, mongoose

**Update:** I found the solution, look in the bottom of this page...

I've got a Node.js, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose project written in CoffeScript and I can create and read data, but I can't update.

This is what my code looks like;

app.js

```
 # update
 app.put "/admin/:id.:format?", (req, res) ->
    Content.findById req.body.content.id, (err, c) ->
        c.title = req.body.content.title
        c.body = req.body.content.body
        c.save (err) ->
            switch req.params.format
                when "json"
                    res.send c.__doc
                else
                    res.redirect "/admin"
```

edit.jade

```
h2 Edit Content
form(method='post', action='/admin/' + c.id)
  input(name='content[id]', value=c.id, type='hidden')
  input(name='_method', value='PUT', type='hidden')
div
  label Title:
    input(name='content[title]', value=c.title || '')
div
  label Body:
    textarea(name='content[body]')=c.body || ''
div
  input(type='submit', value='Save')
```

And this is what my console says

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Thu, 13 Oct 2011 21:39:55 GMT] "POST /admin/4e96ec17fd7da7cb18000001 HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://localhost:1234/admin/4e96ec17fd7da7cb18000001/edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.83 Safari/535.2"
```

And this is what my browser tells me

```
Cannot POST /admin/4e96ec17fd7da7cb18000001
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution on http://expressjs.com/guide.html:

"When using methods such as PUT with a form, we can utilize a hidden input named _method, which can be used to alter the HTTP method. To do so we first need the methodOverride middleware, **which should be placed below bodyParser** so that it can utilize it’s req.body containing the form values."

```
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()
```

Answer (score 5):

The form sends a **POST** request to the server, but your route is for **PUT** requests.

Comment: And in case it's not obvious, do `form(method='put'...` to fix it, or just PUT with ajax like the cool kids do.

Comment: But there is a input(name='_method', value='PUT', type='hidden') that should fix that in Express